# How to get a list of some specific weekdays within a date range in python

Tags: python, python-datetime

I need to get a list of Mondays within a date range.

For example:

```
# selected date range
date_range = ['2019-02-25', '2019-03-25']
# desired output:
mondays = ['2019-02-25', '2019-03-04', '2019-03-11', '2019-03-18', '2019-03-25']

# selected date range
date_range = ['2019-02-25', '2019-03-20']
# desired output
mondays = ['2019-02-25', '2019-03-04', '2019-03-11', '2019-03-18']
```

The starting date is always a Monday.

Does anyone know how I can generate the list of Mondays using python datetime?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55114536/get-the-number-of-week-days-with-date-between-two-dates-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using **[weekday()](https://pythontic.com/datetime/date/weekday)**.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime

def get_mondays(date_start, date_end):
    date_start = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_start, "%Y-%m-%d")
    date_end = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_end, "%Y-%m-%d")

    result = []
    while date_start <= date_end:
        if date_start.weekday() == 0:   #0 == Monday
            result.append(date_start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) 
        date_start += datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    return result

print(get_mondays('2019-02-25', '2019-03-25'))
print(get_mondays('2019-02-25', '2019-03-20'))
```

**Output:**

```
['2019-02-25', '2019-03-04', '2019-03-11', '2019-03-18', '2019-03-25']
['2019-02-25', '2019-03-04', '2019-03-11', '2019-03-18']
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you can use 3rd-party module [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
from dateutil import rrule, parser

def case_of_the_mondays(start,end): 
    mondays = list(rrule.rrule(rrule.WEEKLY,
                               dtstart=parser.parse(start),
                               until=parser.parse(end))) 
    return mondays
```

Result:

```
In [22]: case_of_the_mondays('2019-02-25','2019-03-25')
Out[22]: 
[datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 25, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 4, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 11, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 18, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 25, 0, 0)]
```